# jQuery money count up

Tags: php, jquery

I am new to jQuery. I need to create a money counte up. I want it to start at $1,000,000.34.

The last digits (34) will increment very fast and the 1 million dollar will keep on increasing. I do not want to put a limit so the counter keeps on increasing infinitely. If the user leaves at $1,455,677.34 when he turns back, he should find a bigger amount (meaning that the amount keeps increasing even when the user is not on the website).

I need someone who can direct me into the right direction, so I would be able to build this.

Comment: You need to save it in a db in order for the user to see it the next time.

Comment: Not necessarily, you may use the time as a variable in your function to determine the current amount of money. No need to save anything.

Comment: Save the value in a cookie.

Comment: Yet another "win 1 milliion" website? Not my business, but to ensure we can help you - please clarify few things. Do you all users when coming see $1mil + .34 cents? Or you want it start at $1mil, and other users will see higher value than that first time they visit? Because one solution would involve manipulating with cookies, while for another getting the universal time is enough

Comment: Or localStorage, for that matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to point you in the right direction, see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rHq4u/).

```
window.setInterval(function () {
   var countStart = 1000000.34;

   var count = countStart + (new Date().getTime() 
               - new Date('01/10/2013').getTime())/36000;

   $("#counter").text(count);
}, 1000);
```

You make use of `window.setInterval()` with an interval of `1s`, so the underlying function will be called every second. Next you calculate your current counter value and display it in a div.

You will have to develop a function for calculating the value by yourself, as this one only increases the counter in a linear way, but this would be my general direction and a start if i were to develop such a counter.

There are plenty of other ways to accomplish a functionality like this, as mentioned in the comments to the question. For example, you could make use of a database or cookie for storing the current value, so you don't have to calculate your value in dependency of the current time.